# Why do `AWS: *` S3 bucket policy principals behave like `*` principals?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, permissions, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to host a file in S3 with the following permissions:

- Publicly accessible for AWS resources (specifically, creating a CloudFormation stack using the hosted S3 file).
- Publicly accessible for download from a browser with an active AWS login session.
- NOT publicly accessible without an active AWS login session.

This can be done with ACLs (Access Control Lists); however, those are being deprecated.  I'm trying to recreate this security structure with bucket policies.

The [AWS documentation on bucket policy principals](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html) states under "Grant anonymous permissions":

> Using "Principal": "*" with an Allow effect in a resource-based policy
> allows anyone, even if they’re not signed in to AWS, to access your
> resource.
>
> Using "Principal" : { "AWS" : "*" } with an Allow effect in a
> resource-based policy allows any root user, IAM user, assumed-role
> session, or federated user in any account in the same partition to
> access your resource.

The description of `"Principal" : { "AWS" : "*" }` seems to be incorrect.  Files stored in an S3 bucket that's granted `s3:GetObject` permissions to the above principal are accessible over https via a raw curl request.  This is the behavior described by using `"Principal": "*"`.

```
>>> curl https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/my-file.txt

<my file contents here...>
```

I stood up a CloudFormation stack using the following template expecting to get the security structure I described:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: ''
Resources:
  MyBucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketName: 'my-bucket'
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
        BlockPublicAcls: true
        BlockPublicPolicy: true
        IgnorePublicAcls: true
        RestrictPublicBuckets: false
  MyBucketPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref 'MyBucket'
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Sid: 'AWSAccountAccessOnly'
            Effect: 'Allow'
            Principal:
              AWS: '*'
            Action: 's3:GetObject'
            Resource:
              - !Sub '${MyBucket.Arn}/*'
```

That was not the case, however.  All files stored in `MyBucket` are accessible on the open internet.  Any insight you have on this behavior would be appreciated.

Comment: Regarding "Publicly accessible for download from a browser with an active AWS login session", this isn't going to work. Your request to get an object is either signed with AWS credentials or it's not. Being logged into the AWS console in the same browser is irrelevant to that download request.

Comment: When using the `{ "AWS" : "*" }` principal in your S3 bucket policy, any authenticated request should succeed and any anonymous request should fail. It's probably worth you testing this manually outside of your current automation to verify this behavior. Also, be aware that if you change an S3 bucket policy, there may be some small period of time in which eventual consistency of the policy might impact a request, so wait before testing any policy change.